# sum of CDF and derivation

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have two independent distributions $X$ and $Y$.

$Z=\alpha X + (1-\alpha) Y$ and $\alpha \in [0,1]$.

I want to know the effect of change in alpha on the probability mass in the middle of the support.

For example,

- $X$ is a uniform distribution $\cup{[0,1]}$
- $Y$ is a triangle distribution ${[0,1]}$ with peak $\frac{1}{2}$.

Then, as $\alpha$ goes up, intuitively, $F_{Z(\alpha)}(\frac{2}{3}) -F_{Z(\alpha)}(\frac{1}{3})$ decreases, where $F$ represents CDF.

Is there any way I can show this?

Any comments are welcomed.

**Additional trial**

$F_Z(z)=\int_0^{1}$ $F_X(\frac{z-(1-\alpha)y}{\alpha})f_y(y) dy$

Here, $F_X(x)=x$ therefore,

$F_Z(z)=\int_0^{1} \frac{z-(1-\alpha)y}{\alpha} f_y(y) dy$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

\begin{align*}
\mathbb P\{Z\leq z\}&=\mathbb P\{\alpha X+(1-\alpha )Y\leq z\}\\
&\underset{(1)}{=}\int_0^1\mathbb P\{(1-\alpha )Y\leq z-\alpha x\mid X=x \}\,\mathrm d x\\
&\underset{(2)}{=}\int_0^1 \mathbb P\{(1-\alpha )Y\leq z-\alpha x\}\,\mathrm d x.
\end{align*}

Where $(1)$ comes from formula of total probability and $(2)$ from independence. I let you conclude.

Comment: Thank you! I'm a bit lost in (1). If you have time could you explain a bit more? I think there should be a pdf of X in (1). I will try more in my original question.

Comment: Total probability says $$\mathbb P\{(X,Y)\in E\}=\int_{\mathbb R}\mathbb P\{Y\in E^x\mid X=x\}\mathbb P\{X\in \,\mathrm d x\},$$ where $E^x=\{y\in \mathbb R\mid (x,y)\in E\}$ @EungikLee

Comment: Oh, I see you omitted the pdf part because of uniform distribution. Thanks

Comment: @EungikLee: yes :-)